# simple R foreach example

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm new to R and recently needed to find the index of elements in a list with particular values. I tried to speed up the operation using foreach and also compared two ways of doing this. In the code below 'a' is the list and 'b' are the values whose indices we want to retrieve within 'a':

```
library("iterators")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")
a <- 1:200000
b <- sample(1:200000,100000,replace=TRUE)
registerDoParallel()
getDoParWorkers(); #to see the number of cores
system.time(unlist(lapply(b,function(x) which(a==x))))
system.time(foreach(i<-iter(b),.combine='c') %dopar% { which(a==b) })
```

output:

```
Loading required package: parallel
[1] 32
   user  system elapsed 
124.648   7.460 132.114 
   user  system elapsed 
402.076  59.164  55.260
```

I'm wondering: 1) naively, why is this operation slow? I haven't checked but I'd think a scripting language could do the same thing much faster. 2) Shouldn't the operation scale very well in parallel, it still seems to take longer than expected since I have 32 cores available. 3) in reality I am iterating over the rows of a matrix i.e. foreach(i<-iter(b,by='row'),.combine='c') %dopar% { #stuff }. My understanding is that this approach is best since it will not send the entire matrix to each core. Is there a way to confirm by checking what data each core is receiving?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I could be wrong, but: I know that, in general, compiled languages are faster than interpreted languages (in fact, once you compiled you have the executable in machine language: a script language should be interpreted every time, thus resulting in a loss of time). Then, vectorization in R is useful despite being slower than other languages... but, in my humble opinion (I'm quite new to R too), I lose lot less time in writing in R than in compiled non-vectorizated languages :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do 1e5 * 2e5 comparisons. It's not exactly surprising that this takes some time.

Each individual `which(a==x)` is not that slow and you have a lot of parallelization overhead if you send each iteration separately to the workers. It would be much better to send bunches of iterations. On a non-windows system you can do just that with `mclapply`:

```
a <- 1:20000
b <- sample(1:20000,10000,replace=TRUE)

library(parallel)
system.time(res1 <- unlist(lapply(b,function(x) which(a==x))))
# user      system     elapsed 
#0.597       0.178       0.789 
system.time(res2 <- unlist(mclapply(b,function(x) which(a==x), 
                                    mc.preschedule = TRUE, mc.cores = 3)))
# user      system     elapsed 
#0.004       0.022       0.325 
all.equal(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Regarding 3): There might be better ways than parallelization (best would be matrix algebra), but it depends on your `#stuff`.

Comment: thanks, parallelization overhead is something I am getting used to thinking about.